# Intellij checkout from github

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, git-checkout

I am using Intellij Idea Ultimate edition 14.0.3. my **Git** plugin tests successfully but when I create a new workspace and try to checkout my project using **Github** it gives me an error -

> Service unavailable

I have tried using both Auth Types - Password and Token, but looks like I am not connecting to the Github repository. I have double checked my user credentials and they are correct. My host name also follows the expected syntax :-

`ssh://git@......git`

When I test the Github connection, the error message is as under:

```
Can't login: Can't get user info
Service Unavailable
```

Is there an issue with my proxy? I am using the default Proxy settings.

Comment: What's your OS? Did you try git clone from the command line?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and I have not tried that. How do I do so?

Comment: I just tried using 14.1.1 and the github integration, no problems at all. Just added my username/password and it worked out of the box.

Comment: Download and install [Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io). Don't forget to choose the shell integration (option 2). Then inside a cmd prompt (or the git shell) enter `git clone git@github.com/yourname/yourrepo` and see if it works

Comment: Okay I did that.. Its not accepting my credentials on the command line, but when I try to sign in to the repository on a browser, it lets me in successfully. I get the following authentication error on command line after 3 password attempts(even though it is the correct password) :                     "Permission denied. fatal: could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

Comment: My bad, try the _https_ URL (`https://www.github.com/...`) instead or the _ssh_ URL (`git@github.com`). The ssh uses _rsa/dsa key authentication_ that you may haven't configured yet whereas the https uses your GitHub _user/password authentication_. BTW tell me if it works so I can write all it down on a clean answer

Comment: There is also the option of choosing _Git_ instead of _GitHub_ and configure your repo bypassing the GitHub integration that is maybe failing in your case.

Comment: Okay, I figured out your problem, it is the hostname, it should be github.com, not the repository url, see my answer for the details

Comment: Okay, so my url is ssh://git@stash........git. Is that okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the `https:` style url, instead of `ssh:`

e.g.

```
https://github.com/My-name/my-repo.git
```

I suggest to create a new intellij project and check out your repo via the menu: `VCS` -> `Checkout from Version Control` -> `Git`

Comment: Okay, I can check out the project successfully using the above. However, when I go the new workspace, my code is not connected to the GIT version control. Hence, I cannot do an Update or Check in etc, since the code is not connected to Git.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the right *hostname*.

`ssh://git@......git` is your *repository*, not your hostname.

The hostname should be simply: `github.com`.

When you have successfully connected, IntelliJ IDEA will let you choose your repository. See "[Cloning a Repository from GitHub](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cloning-a-repository-from-github.html)" for more information about that.